# making pdf as password protected with java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to make an existing PDF as password protected for which I'm using the itext I am following this URL

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/29/create-pdf-files-in-java-itext-tutorial/

I have developed a program which will send the mail with the PDF as attachment. Below is the code where I am making the PDF file as password protected.

Right now the PDF file is attached in mail but when I am trying to open it, I get an error that it is damaged.

What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
//  attachment part
MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String filename = "c:\\SettingupRulesin outlook2003.pdf";

//OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("PasswordProtected.pdf"));
final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
com.itextpdf.text.Document doc = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, os);
writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),
                     OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                     PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); 

os.close();


DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachPart.setFileName(filename);
```

Comment: You are saving the file locally before you send it as an attachment - what does that local file look like? Can you open it there? How big is the file?

Comment: yeah the file is stored locally in my system  and this is a pdf file of less than 2  mb in size i want to send it as a attachment through mail which is happening but i want to make it as a password protected also which is not happening

Comment: If the PDF that is stored locally is a working PDF with a working password, then the problem you are experiencing is **not an iText problem.** If that is the case, then iText is not the culprit and you should choose other tags for your question.

Comment: You use a `PdfWriter`. That class can be used to create new PDFs from scratch, not to manipulate existing ones. Please use a `PdfStamper` instead which is for manipulating existing documents.

Comment: @Jongware You're right, most of the time I do. I'll be alert!

Answer (score 1):

You use a `PdfWriter`. That class can be used to create new PDFs from scratch, not to manipulate existing ones. Please use a `PdfStamper` instead which is for manipulating existing documents.